# Looking for help choosing a voltage converter / regulator for microcontroller

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck, linear-regulator

I am designing a board that will need 3.3 V, 2.8 V, 1.5 V, and ideally 1.2 V rails. The board will be powered by a 12 V power supply so for stepping from 12 V to 3.3 V I am planning on using a buck converter for efficiency, but since stepping from 3.3 V to 2.8 V is much smaller, I was thinking about just using a linear voltage regulator, and then chaining regulators to get to 1.2 V.

Whatever power distribution I go with, I need it to be compact, cheap, and efficient. Is it smarter to use multiple buck converters, multiple linear regulators, or a mix of both?

Ideally, I would find some part that has all 4 rails in a convenient SMD package, but I haven't found that part yet.

Comment: I wouldn't get your hopes up about finding a single part that can give you all four (or three, if you're using a buck for the 3.3, which I conditionally recommend) voltages.  I'm looking at some that can do 2.8, 1.8, and 1.5 together, but I think you'll have a much easier time just getting some single- or dual-output LDOs and running them from your 3.3V rail.  Of course, any more specific advice would depend on your requirements for current, ripple, transient response, power dissipation, etc etc.

Comment: This sounds like exactly the type of application SIMO are designed for. (Single Inductor Multiple Output buck switching regulators)  See for example this paper (note: I am an applications engineer at Maxim - now Analog Devices) https://www.maximintegrated.com/content/dam/files/design/technical-documents/white-papers/simo-switching-regulators-extending-battery-life-for-hearables-and-wearables.pdf

Comment: @MarkU These look really cool. Thanks

Comment: @MarkU - that's neat. But 2.8V might be a problem if it uses up too much of the on-time duty cycle.

Comment: You could just use a diode in series from the 3.3v to generate your 2.8v rail. Likely it will be 2.7v but most chips can handle a 0.1V delta.

Comment: People here will close this question

Comment: You will have to specify current ratings of the rails, to get more sensible answers. As it is now, the best people could answer, is recommending multiple output switched converters, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chain all the lower voltage through the 3.3V converter, the power dissipation of the first LDO (3.3V -> 2.8V) could be rather higher, as all current has to pass through it.

Instead, you could derive them all directly from the 3.3V with individual converters. If current demand for a particular rail is low, you can also consider switched capacitor converters. They are quite simple/small, have high efficiency, but bring quite a bit of output ripple, so check carefully.

It all depends on the current ratings of the individual rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you can mount a BGA chip, this one can supply your 4 different voltages by setting each with a cap and resistor.
They are a bit spendy but you didn't give a budget.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc/LTM8001IY-PBF/3934651

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a similar solution and ran across the [MAX679*X*](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6791-MAX6796.pdf) series, several of which are dual-output.